# How to pass variable to next page without passing it in the URL or using sessions?

Tags: php

I want to pass a variable to another page but there is going to be multiple variables eg:

```
<a href=view.php?viewkey=mnbvc>View</a> 
<a href=view.php?viewkey=vcbvc>View</a> 
<a href=view.php?viewkey=uiytj>View</a> 
<a href=view.php?viewkey=wegnv>View</a>
```

It will look something like that, but doing that the view key is passed in the url which i don't want happen, is there anyway to pass it hidden from the user?

Comment: you can use ajax for this

Comment: You can pass it as POST data instead of GET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @adeneo's comment, use `POST` request instead of `GET`.

```
<form method="post" action="view.php">
    <select name="viewkey" required="required">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Choose an option</option>
        <option value="mnbvc">mnbvc</option>
        <option value="vcbvc">vcbvc</option>
        <option value="uiytj">uiytj</option>
        <option value="wegnv">wegnv</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Pass the variable</button>
</form>
```

And fetch it in `view.php` like so:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_POST))
{
    var_dump($_POST['viewkey']);
}
```

Comment: Glad it did. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You could a POST instead.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="linkToPage" data-key="mnbvc">View</a>
```

Then using Jquery,
- get the key attribute, set it the form and submit the form to view.php

eg.

```
$('.linkToPage').click(function(){ 
    $('#formInput').val($(this).data('key'));
    $('#form').submit();
});
```

Your form could be like this :

```
<form id="form" action="view.php">
  <input type="hidden" id="formInput">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to hide the values from the user you may use POST variables and will need to embed the values in a form.  Apply this either by simple HTML or With JQuery to the next page. e.g. use radio buttons with same name onclick pass the value by submit button...